# Unable to initiate replica set while createing config server to deploy sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I am trying to deploy a sharded cluster in MongoDB in mac. I am following [this](https://premaseem.wordpress.com/2016/02/14/mongodb-script-to-run-sharding-with-replica-set-on-local-machine/) page. For creating a config server for sharded cluster I did the following steps

```
mkdir -p /data/config/config-a /data/config/config-b /data/config/config-c
mongod --logpath "cfg-a.log" --dbpath /data/config/config-a --port 57040 --fork --configsvr --smallfiles
mongod --logpath "cfg-b.log" --dbpath /data/config/config-b --port 57041 --fork --configsvr --smallfiles
mongod --logpath "cfg-c.log" --dbpath /data/config/config-c --port 57042 --fork --configsvr --smallfiles
```

and after this I tried initiating the replica set, as follows

```
$ mongo --port 57040

> config = { _id : "cs", members : [{ _id:0, host:"localhost:57040"}, { _id:1, host: "localhost:57041"}, { _id:2, host:"localhost:57042"}]};
{
    "_id" : "cs",
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "localhost:57040"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "localhost:57041"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "localhost:57042"
        }
    ]
> rs.initiate(config)
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "This node was not started with the replSet option",
    "code" : 76,
    "codeName" : "NoReplicationEnabled"
}
```

Why am I getting this error ? I did not get any error while initiating other replica sets but I am getting error in this one. Could someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The guide you are following is outdated. MongoDB documentation has a [tutorial that configures a sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/). It gives both `--replSet` and `--configsvr` arguments:

```
mongod --configsvr --replSet <replica set name> --dbpath <path> --bind_ip localhost,<hostname(s)|ip address(es)>
```

Comment: I assume this is the command for creating config server replica set. Should this be replaced with the three lines I have mentioned after "mkdir"

Comment: I am having this problem while creating the configserver replica set. I assume the command you gave is for starting it after creating a replicaset for config server

Comment: I suggest following the MongoDB tutorial from the beginning.